# redirect to login page of website, if a user denies facebook permissions

Tags: facebook

I am implementing a facebook integration to a website. If user denies facebook permissions, how can I redirect them back to my website?

Answer (score 4):

As @abraham has already mentioned that user denial also redirects to your redirect_uri, all you have to do is check if the user has denied permissions.

The following is how facebook redirects to your url, i.e. the redirect_uri , when the user has denied permissions.

> http://
>   YOUR_URL?error_reason=user_denied&
>        error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

So in your code you can check if the `error` and/or `error_reason` and/or `error_description` fields are set in the url, and then do whatever specific actions you want to do when user denies.
Some code to help you out:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['error'])){//ok some error has occurred from Facebook
  if(isset($_REQUEST['error_reason']) && $_REQUEST['error_reason']=='user_denied'){// ok so the error has occurred coz the user denied permissions!
    // a lot of apps render a static page explaining why it needs the permission it has asked for, you can  do the same here!
    // more code
  }
}

 // rest of you code ...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi. I used your code in my php application. When a user first denies the permissions, it works fine and I am able to redirect the user to the request permissions once again.But next if the user accepts to give permissions, the user is redirected continuously between facebook and my app canvas url. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: @ASHUTOSH if the user accepts, then the url will not contain `$_REQUEST['error']`, and my code is handling only that behavior, so there has to be something else wrong in your code. have you asked a specific question regarding this? i'd be happy to look into it, if you wish, reply with your question's link. it's difficult to say anything without seeing your code. i'd just be guessing

Comment: following is the link to the question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343578/redirection-between-facebook-and-my-app-canvas-never-stops

Answer (score 0):

Technically, if the user is still on your site you can do that but if on facebook's site, then they can automatically provide redirect instruction in their codes. implementing this should give you a basic idea on how to get the user back to your site.

```
          $siteurl = 'http://www.mysiteexample.com';
         if ( isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
                        $redirect_to = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];

                    } else {

                            //
                            $redirect_to =  'siteurl' .'/'.$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook's authentication page. If they user denies access they will get redirected to your redirect_uri with an error. You can check if the error is there and redirect to the homepage.

> If the user presses Don't Allow, your app is not authorized. The OAuth Dialog will redirect (via HTTP 302) the user's browser to the URL you passed in the redirect_uri parameter with the following error information:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/